# Karma/Jasmine test failing on undefined scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

I'm trying to create first unit testing for one of my controllers.

My Karma/Jasmine simple test for a controller looks like

```
describe('RegistrationController', function() {

    beforeEach(module('myApp'));

    var $controller, $rootScope;

    beforeEach(inject(function(_$controller_, _$rootScope_){
        // The injector unwraps the underscores (_) from around the parameter names when matching
        $controller = _$controller_;
        $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    }));

    describe('Registration $scope.submit', function() {
        it('submits registration and sets step to 1', function() {
            var $scope = $rootScope.$new();

            var controller = $controller('RegistrationController', { $scope: $scope });
            $scope.submit();
            expect($scope.step).toEqual(1);
        });
    }); 

});
```

which tests that part of the controller

```
$scope.submit = function () {

    $scope.step = 1; //wizard started
    var userName = $scope.user.name;
    var userNick = $scope.user.nick;        
    $location.path('localization');
}
```

but when I run that unit test it fails on `user.name` and `user.nick` with an error

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

or

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'nick' of undefined`

when both values are captured by the form and works fine on the controller side.

Comment: define $scope.user = {name: "xyz", nick :"abc"} in your test suit it will work

Comment: @VijayKrishna that did the job. Thanks!